# 'System.IO.Stream' does not contain a definition for 'Close' in Windows Store Apps

Tags: .net, windows-8, stream, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

When try to build my Unity 3D project on Windows Store Apps, this error occurs

> System.IO.Stream' does not contain a definition for 'Close' and no extension method 'Close' accepting a first argument of type 'System.IO.Stream' could be found

How can I use Streams in Windows 8?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get that error because there is no support for Stream.Close on Windows Store Apps.

As is stated on the [.Net for Windows Store apps overview page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

> The subset of managed types and members was designed with a clear focus on Windows Store app development. As a result, it omits the following:
>
> [...]
>
> - Members that cause confusion (such as the Close method on I/O types).

You will have to replace that with a `Dispose()` or by using a `using` statement.