# Why windows 10 UWP framework Stream class does not have Close method?

Tags: c#, stream, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

Why windows 10 UWP framework Stream class does not have Close method?

What do I do in order to release the used stream, I have used Dispose method as of now but is there any other way I can release the stream?

And why microsoft have removed Close method from the Stream class?

Comment: Which namespace are you using specifically? ``System.IO`` or ``Windows::Storage::Streams``?

Comment: It's not clear if this question is referring to System.IO.Stream but if it is, then [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533079/system-io-stream-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-close-in-unity3d-for-wind) is a dupe (the Unity bit is irrelevant).

Comment: @BoltClock: the Unity3d aspect is a red herring in that other question, and the mention of it makes it somewhat hard to follow the Q&A. But yes, that appears to be fundamentally the same question.

Comment: @Peter Duniho: [I had nothing better to do](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18533079/revisions)

Answer (score 3):

You are indeed supposed to be using `Dispose()`, or better yet enclosing your streams in a using block. MSDN says you're not expected to call [`System.IO.Stream.Close()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx) directly and you should be calling `Dispose()` instead anyway. So there isn't much of an issue here.